# make \w match characters like ÄÖÜäöüß?

Tags: regex, sublime-text-2

Is it possible to customize the behavior of regex metacharacters for character classes like that?

(In Sublime, or more generally.)

Comment: Sublime uses [Boost's Perl regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) syntax, and you cannot change that implementation. Maybe you could write a plugin that does something more fancy in Python.

Answer (score 0):

if @slhck is right, and Sublime is using Boot's pcre syntax, you should be able to use `\p{L}` in place of `\w` and that should give you what you need.

Ref: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/character_classes/optional_char_class_names.html

Comment: Hm. Nope, `x\p{L}x` doesn't match the string `xüx` in Sublime.

Comment: (It does match `xax`.)